# How to contact Twitter to report phishing scams

Tags: twitter, phishing

Every week I get an email message from somebody asking me to confirm my Twitter account. I don't even have a Twitter account! The sender's email address is `activate@twitter.com`, which I find suspicious as it is so generic and does not include the sender's name, which appears in the subject line. I have never opened any of his emails as I suspect this is a malicious phishing scam. In the meantime, I have blocked it so the emails end up in my spam box. Also, I want to report the above to Twitter to see if they can do anything about it, should it be a legitimate user, which I doubt. How do I email or call them as I am not a Twitter user?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a letter to their legal department, send it as registered mail, return receipt requested to:

Vijaya Gadde, Esq.
Sean Edgett, Esq.
Twitter, Inc.
1355 Market Street, Suite 900
San Francisco, California 94103
(415) 222-9670

Make sure you provide information for them to contact you back because all your letter will do is **if you are lucky** prompt them to forward the problem to someone in the organization who will research the issue.